# Create daily rolling current highest Value series

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data which has a `Value`, `Time` and `Date` column:

[image: raw_date_img]

**Desired output**

I would like to create a new Series capturing the rows for current highest `Value` as follows in this example:

[image: img2]

This looks at the `Value` column each day and captures the recent highest `Value`.

- At 9:00 on 1/1/00 the `Value` was 2 so this was the highest.
- At 17:00 on 1/1/00 the `Value` was 3 so we capture this.

Please see df.to_dict() below to reproduce this:

```
 df.to_dict()

    {'Date': {0: Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'),
      1: Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'),
      2: Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'),
      3: Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00'),
      4: Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00'),
      5: Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00'),
      6: Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00'),
      7: Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00'),
      8: Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00'),
      9: Timestamp('2000-01-04 00:00:00'),
      10: Timestamp('2000-01-04 00:00:00'),
      11: Timestamp('2000-01-04 00:00:00')},
     'Time': {0: datetime.time(9, 0),
      1: datetime.time(13, 0),
      2: datetime.time(17, 0),
      3: datetime.time(9, 0),
      4: datetime.time(13, 0),
      5: datetime.time(17, 0),
      6: datetime.time(9, 0),
      7: datetime.time(13, 0),
      8: datetime.time(17, 0),
      9: datetime.time(9, 0),
      10: datetime.time(13, 0),
      11: datetime.time(17, 0)},
     'Value': {0: 2,
      1: 2,
      2: 3,
      3: 2,
      4: 3,
      5: 3,
      6: 1,
      7: 1,
      8: 1,
      9: 3,
      10: 1,
      11: 2}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need to use [`cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.cummax.html) to get the cumulative maximum for the `Value` column followed by dropping off duplicated entries after grouping them w.r.t `Date` column.

```
grouped = df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda x: x['Value'].cummax()            \
                                                       .drop_duplicates())   \
                                                       .reset_index()
print(df[df.index.isin(grouped['level_1'])])

        Date      Time  Value
0 2000-01-01  09:00:00      2
2 2000-01-01  17:00:00      3
3 2000-01-02  09:00:00      2
4 2000-01-02  13:00:00      3
6 2000-01-03  09:00:00      1
9 2000-01-04  09:00:00      3
```